# Cypher - Attempting to print all nodes to text o/p exceeds Java Heap space - Neo4j V 3.5

Tags: printing, neo4j, heap-memory, nodes

Attempting to print all the node properties of my large graph to a human readable text file leads to a out of Heap space error although Heap space has been made huge (256GB)

Example Cypher:
match (n:Entity)  return n, n.links_to, n.links_from;

echo "match (n:Entity)  return n, n.links_to, n.links_from;" | /home/user/neo4j-enterprise/bin/cypher-shell > all_node_links.out

Is there a more efficient/practical way of doing this for large graphs ?
I do not wish to export to a CSV file as I wish to parse the resultant text file in bash shell/sed.

Answer (score 0):

Just found an Apoc function to solve this:

call apoc.export.csv.query('MATCH (n:Entity) Return n.name,n.links_from,n.links_to', '/home/user/all_node_links.csv', {} );